# Using child classes polymorphically with differing return types

Tags: vb.net, polymorphism

I have two Parser classes that inherit from a base class, BaseParser.  I want to use either class as a parameter in another Monitor class.  The Parser classes, CS600 and TCH600, both have two properties, RawDataList and SummaryDataList.  The CS600 class's RawDataList returns a List(of CS600Data); the TCH600 RawDataList returns a List(of TCH600Data).  The SummaryDataList returns similar classes in each Parser class.  CS600Data and TCH600Data derive from a base class, BaseData.
BaseParser also has RawDataList (List(of BaseData)) and SummaryDataList (List(of BaseSummaryData))

The Monitor class has a private field, _thisParser which can be either of the two concrete Parsers above.  I want to be able to call and use RawDataList and SummaryDataList of _thisParser within Monitor class, but when I construct the concrete Parser classes, Visual Studio notes that the RawDataList property of CS600 cannot override the RawDataList property of the BaseParser because they differ in their return types.

I thought that since CS600Data derived from BaseData (but also adds some new properties of its own) that I could use CS600Data wherever I use BaseData.  What am I misunderstanding?  How can I correctly construct these classes?

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseParser

    Protected _rawDataList As List(Of RawGasData.BaseData)
    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property RawDataList() As List(Of RawGasData.BaseData)

    Protected _summaryDataList As List(Of SummaryGasData.BaseSummaryData)
    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property SummaryDataList() As List(Of SummaryGasData.BaseSummaryData)

    Public Event GasDataCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal dataFilePath As String, ByVal unit As String)
        Load(dataFilePath, unit)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Load(ByVal dataFilePath As String, ByVal unit As String)
        Dim contents = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(dataFilePath)
        ParseRawData(contents)
        GenerateSummaryData(contents, unit)
        RaiseEvent GasDataCreated(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

    Protected MustOverride Sub ParseRawData(ByVal fileContents As String)

    Protected MustOverride Sub GenerateSummaryData(ByVal fileContents As String, ByVal unit As String)

End Class

Public Class CS600Parser
    Inherits BaseParser

    Shadows _rawDataList As List(Of RawGasData.CS600Data)
    'Cannot override base class' RawDataList - differ by their return types
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property RawDataList() As List(Of RawGasData.CS600Data)
        Get
            Return _rawDataList
        End Get
    End Property

    Shadows _summaryDataList As List(Of SummaryGasData.CS600SummaryData)
    'Cannot override base class' SummaryDataList - differ by their return types
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property SummaryDataList() As List(Of SummaryGasData.CS600SummaryData)
        Get
            Return _summaryDataList
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub ParseRawData(ByVal fileContents As String)
        Dim data = From d In fileContents.Trim.Split(CChar(vbCrLf)) _
                   Let fields = d.Split(","c).Select(Function(s) s.Trim) _
                   Select New RawGasData.CS600Data With { _
                        .SampleNumber = fields(0), _
                        .UserID = fields(1), _
                        .CarbonValue = CDbl(fields(2)), _
                        .SulfurValue = CDbl(fields(3))}

        _rawDataList = data.ToList

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub GenerateSummaryData(ByVal fileContents As String, ByVal unit As String)
        Dim groupedData = From d In _rawDataList _
                          Group By d.SampleNumber Into Group _
                          Select New SummaryGasData.CS600SummaryData With { _
                            .DataTimeStamp = Now, _
                            .SampleNumber = SampleNumber, _
                            .UserID = Group.First.UserID, _
                            .CarbonAverage = Group.Select(Function(s) s.CarbonValue).Average, _
                            .CarbonUnit = unit, _
                            .SulfurAverage = Group.Select(Function(s) s.SulfurValue).Average, _
                            .SulfurUnit = unit}

        _summaryDataList = groupedData.ToList

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class TCHParser
    Inherits BaseParser

    Shadows _rawDataList As List(Of RawGasData.TCH600Data)
    'Cannot override base class' RawDataList - differ by their return types
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property RawDataList() As List(Of RawGasData.TCH600Data)
        Get
            Return _rawDataList
        End Get
    End Property

    Shadows _summaryDataList As List(Of SummaryGasData.TCH600SummaryData)
    'Cannot override base class' SummaryDataList - differ by their return types
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property SummaryDataList() As List(Of SummaryGasData.TCH600SummaryData)
        Get
            Return _summaryDataList
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub ParseRawData(ByVal fileContents As String)
        Dim data = From d In fileContents.Trim.Split(CChar(vbCrLf)) _
       Let fields = d.Split(","c).Select(Function(s) s.Trim) _
       Select New RawGasData.TCH600Data With { _
            .SampleNumber = fields(0), _
            .UserID = fields(1), _
            .OxygenValue = CDbl(fields(2)), _
            .NitrogenValue = CDbl(fields(3)), _
            .HydrogenValue = CDbl(fields(4)), _
            .MassUsed = CDbl(fields(5))}

        _rawDataList = data.ToList

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub GenerateSummaryData(ByVal fileContents As String, ByVal unit As String)
        Dim groupedData = From d In _rawDataList _
                          Group By d.SampleNumber Into Group _
                          Select New SummaryGasData.TCH600SummaryData With { _
                            .DataTimeStamp = Now, _
                            .SampleNumber = SampleNumber, _
                            .UserID = Group.First.UserID, _
                            .OxygenAverage = Group.Select(Function(s) s.OxygenValue).Average, _
                            .OxygenUnit = unit, _
                            .NitrogenAverage = Group.Select(Function(s) s.NitrogenValue).Average, _
                            .NitrogenUnit = unit, _
                            .HydrogenAverage = Group.Select(Function(s) s.HydrogenValue).Average, _
                            .HydrogenUnit = unit}

        _summaryDataList = groupedData.ToList
    End Sub


End Class


 Public MustInherit Class BaseData
    Implements IGasData

    Private _massUsed As Double
    Public Property MassUsed() As Double Implements IGasData.MassUsed
        Get
            Return _massUsed
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _massUsed = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _sampleNumber As String
    Public Property SampleNumber() As String Implements IGasData.SampleNumber
        Get
            Return _sampleNumber
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _sampleNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _userID As String
    Public Property UserID() As String Implements IGasData.UserID
        Get
            Return _userID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _userID = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class CS600Data
    Inherits BaseData


    Private _carbonValue As Double
    Public Property CarbonValue() As Double
        Get
            Return _carbonValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _carbonValue = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private _sulfurValue As Double
    Public Property SulfurValue() As Double
        Get
            Return _sulfurValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _sulfurValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class TCH600Data
    Inherits BaseData

    Private _oxygenValue As Double
    Public Property OxygenValue() As Double
        Get
            Return _oxygenValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _oxygenValue = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private _nitrogenValue As Double
    Public Property NitrogenValue() As Double
        Get
            Return _nitrogenValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _nitrogenValue = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private _hydrogenValue As Double
    Public Property HydrogenValue() As Double
        Get
            Return _hydrogenValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _hydrogenValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: You should tag the question with the approriate language (VB?), and not with 'visual-studio' unless the question actually deals with VS. You should also post the code of your classes and point out the area where where you have questions.

Comment: Thanks, @KendallFrey; I made the changes you recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overridden list properties, such as `RawDataList`, should be the type of the abstract base class (or better yet `IGasData`), and not the derived class for polymorphism to work. If you find that making the lists of type `BaseData` or `IGasData` is causing problems, you might want to check if your design adheres to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf).

A simplified illustration which compiles and runs just fine (VB.Net 2010):

```
Sub Main    
    Dim parser As BaseParser = New TCHParser()
    Console.WriteLine(parser)   
End Sub

Public MustInherit Class BaseData    
    Public Property SampleNumber() As String
End Class

Public Class TCH600Data 
    Inherits BaseData

    Public Property OxygenValue() As Double
End Class

Public MustInherit Class BaseParser
    Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property RawDataList As List(of BaseData)
End Class
```

`TCHParser` works just fine overriding the `RawDataList` property. Also, I'm not sure why the abstract base class had a `Protected _rawDataList` field. Remove it and you no longer have to worry about shadowing that field in derived types.

```
Public Class TCHParser 
    Inherits BaseParser

    ' Populate the list just so we can test easily.
    Public Sub New()
        Dim data As New List(Of BaseData)
        data.Add(New TCH600Data With {
            .SampleNumber = "1", _
            .OxygenValue = 1.5d })

        data.Add(New TCH600Data With {
            .SampleNumber = "2", _
            .OxygenValue = 2.5d })

        _rawDataList = data
    End Sub

    Private _rawDataList As List(of BaseData)  
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property RawDataList As List(of BaseData)
        Get
            Return _rawDataList
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, @Matt, but it doesn't resolve the return types problem.  I'll revisit the LSP to see what I am missing.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you, @Matt; that really clarified how to approach the problem.